# VBA error 1004 while merging cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, merge

I have no idea how to program in VBA and I'm trying to merge cells that repeat themselves every 13 cells in an excel table. I was able to find the below code but when I apply it I get an error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" and when I debug I get the indication that the issue is in the line .Merge

Can someone help me??

```vba
Sub Test()
TitleRow = 1 'if title contain more than one row, change the value 1 to the actual number of rows'
i = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do
    Set StartCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & (TitleRow + 13 * i + 1))
    Set EndCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & (TitleRow + 13 * i + 13))
    With ActiveSheet.Range(StartCell, EndCell)
        .Merge
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    i = i + 1
    Loop Until Range("B" & (TitleRow + 13 * i) + 1) = ""
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What code line causes the error? What is the type and the value of variant/object variables used in this line in that moment? Define all local variables by `Dim` stmt with proper datatype. Replace ActiveSheet with the reference variable (`set sht = thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1")`). Where the code is typed? it must be common module.

Comment: PS. I have tested: create new workbook, fill B1:B40, copy the code to common module, execute the code - no error.

Comment: The type of variant/object is a text string. And it is typed in a common module
I will try the replace sheet with the reference as you say

Comment: Have you tried merging empty cells, or cells where only one cell has a value?

Comment: I've tried both and I still get the same error